# My code to automatically multiply cells by a value keeps crashing

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to multiply the values in one cell by a number if another cell has a certain string value. However, the code keeps crashing and I'm not sure what is wrong. Before I had a simple sub and it worked fine, but I then updated it to an event sub so that the cell would automatically update when the string value changes.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    For Each cell In Range("I3:I" & Range("I3").End(xlDown).Row)
        If cell.Value = "gallons" Then
            cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = val(cell.Offset(0, -1)) * 0.00378541
        ElseIf cell.Value = "m3" Then
            cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = val(cell.Offset(0, -1))
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every change you make in your sub will re-trigger the event again, unless you disable the event before running any updates.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    On Error Goto haveError
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    For Each cell In Range("I3:I" & Range("I3").End(xlDown).Row)
        If cell.Value = "gallons" Then
            cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = val(cell.Offset(0, -1)) * 0.00378541
        ElseIf cell.Value = "m3" Then
            cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = val(cell.Offset(0, -1))
        End If
    Next

haveError:
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume the reason is
`Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)`.

You run this code each time a value changes.
And the code itself changes values, which means it calls the function again and again and again.

Make sure to turn off the calculations before you change values in this function.
Either manually or with `Application.calculation = xlCalculationManual`

You could possibly also set the target range.
If you have a specific cell that you use as a "trigger" then you can use a if like:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$A$1" Then
        For Each cell In Range("I3:I" & Range("I3").End(xlDown).Row)
            If cell.Value = "gallons" Then

cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = val(cell.Offset(0, -1)) * 0.00378541
            ElseIf cell.Value = "m3" Then

cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = val(cell.Offset(0, -1))
            End If
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Which means the code will only run if you change the value in A1, this not loop itself to destruction.